# can't route /admin to user/login if not login in cakephp

Tags: authentication, routes, admin, cakephp-2.0

i want to create a admin routing enabled program in cakephp and  i had aleray enable
Route::Write(/admin,array('controller'=>admin_homes,'action'=>'index')) in route .php but  when i type /admin it doesnot redirect me to my login page in users/login address so what is solution to this but if i custom go into my login page and login in  then it will redirect to admin/admin_homes/index and then only using/admin will also take me to admin_homes/index

Comment: try this code: Router::connect('/admin/*', array('controller' => 'admin_home'));

Answer (score 0):

You want more than admin routing, you are looking for Authentication. That is what controls the login, not admin routing. Admin routing is for running the admin variation of specific methods.

Start here: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html

If you are looking for a simple user management app with permission driven access, feel free to use the one I created and put out on github. https://github.com/cdburgess/SUM-Cake